# How to create tables for roles and users automatically using identity framework with code first approach in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am creating an application and have made two tables but want to create tables of AspNetRoles, AspNetUsers, AspNetUsersRoles etc tables by code first approach. How would it create without using DB first approach or manually making tables

```
 public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
        createRolesandUsers();
    }
    private void createRolesandUsers()
    {
        ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();

        var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));
        var UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));


        // In Startup iam creating first Admin Role and creating a default Admin User    
        if (!roleManager.RoleExists("SuperAdmin"))
        {

            // first we create Admin rool   
            var role = new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole();
            role.Name = "SuperAdmin";
            roleManager.Create(role);

            //Here we create a Admin super user who will maintain the website                  

            var user = new ApplicationUser();
            user.UserName = "abc";
            user.Email = "abc@gmail.com";

            string userPWD = "password";

            var chkUser = UserManager.Create(user, userPWD);

            //Add default User to Role Admin   
            if (chkUser.Succeeded)
            {
                var result1 = UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "SuperAdmin");

            }
        }

        //creating Creating Manager role
        if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Manager"))
        {
            var role = new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole();
            role.Name = "Manager";
            roleManager.Create(role);

        }

        // creating Creating Employee role    
        if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Employee"))
        {
            var role = new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole();
            role.Name = "Employee";
            roleManager.Create(role);

        }
    }
```

I have done like this and have not done else

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right you just need to extend IdentityDbContext which is part of Identity Framework and generate a migration. This is a way to do code first approach.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

Comment: I am not wokring with core. Simple asp.net mvc 5

Comment: To enable migrations for 'RealTimeNotificationSystem.Models.RealTimeContext', use Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName RealTimeNotificationSystem.Models.RealTimeContext. Here whatis the meaning of -ContextTypeName?

Comment: I have done with database but did not make migrations so there is no folder of migrations in project. Migration History of database has updated although